# Liferay 6.2 adding a new ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I want to add a new ckeditor to my liferay because we need to limit the functionality of the one available. However, I do not want to change the original one because we migth later on need it in a different form.

How can I add a new ckeditor that can be used to create a structure for webcontent articles? Do I need to create a new Theme for liferay or something like this?

Info: Our liferay runs on a Jboss server

**EDIT:**

I have created a hook that overrides the `html\js\editor\ckeditor\ckconfig.jsp` file and added

```
config.toolbar_Mini = [ 
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'], 
    ['BulletedList'] 
];
```

Additionally, I have changed the lines in the concerning the `liferay-ui:input editor` in the `\html\portlet\journal\article\content.jsp` file.

```
<div class="journal-article-component-container">
    <liferay-ui:input-editor contentsLanguageId="<%= Validator.isNotNull(toLanguageId) ? toLanguageId : defaultLanguageId %>" editorImpl="<%= EDITOR_WYSIWYG_IMPL_KEY %>" name="articleContent" toolbarSet="Mini" width="100%" />
</div>
```

Other `toolbarSet` options which are already available (e.g. `phone`or `simple` ) also have no effect.
I also restarted my jboss-server several times - still no effect.

Also it seems, that changes made in the `html\js\editor\ckeditor\config.js` file have absolutely no effect on anything (e.g `alert("foo")`).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `toolbarSet` attribute of `lifeary-ui:input-editor` tag.

You have to override ckconfig.jsp using liferay-plugin hook to add your custom ckeditor configuration which represent your customr toolbar.

e.g. Add below code to ckconfig.jsp.

`config.toolbar_customToolbar=[
        ['FontSize', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike']];`

And then while using `lifeary-ui:input-editor` tag, provide toolbarSet attribute value as `toolbarSet=custom-toolbar`.

FYI: text formatter is used to map config.toolbar_XXXXX so custom-toolbar value of toolbarSet will map to customToolbar (config.toolbar_customToolbar).

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I change the `toolbarSet` in my `content.jsp` file of the ckeditor, where the `liferay-ui:input-editor` tag is, to he name of my toolbar, nothing happens. 
I've created a toolbar `config.toolbar_Mini` and added it with `toolbarSet="Mini"`.

Comment: Please let me know complete detail what you have tried?

Comment: I have created a hook that overrides the `html\js\editor\ckeditor\ckconfig.jsp` file and added `config.toolbar_Mini = [
     ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
     ['BulletedList']
 ];`. Additionally, I have changed the lines in the concerning the `liferay-ui:input editor`in the `\html\portlet\journal\article\content.jsp` file. I also restarted my jboss-server several times - still no effect.

Comment: Thanks for details, would it be possible for you to update question with exact change details ?

Comment: Thanks, I did not get your last statement `Also it seems, that changes made in the html\js\editor\ckeditor\config.js file have absolutely no effect on anything (e.g alert("foo")).`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111697/discussion-between-massimo-rosin-and-pankajkumar-kathiriya).