# Liferay 6.2 wysiwyg editor changes in portal-ext.properties not working

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I need to limit the functionality of the ckeditor in liferay 6.2 for the journal-articles. I tried different approaches like hooks which override the `ckconfig.jsp` with a new toolbar (see my other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114324/liferay-6-2-adding-a-new-ckeditor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141391/custom-ckeditor-toolbar-in-liferay-6-2)), but that did not work. Now I found another way that could work by defining different editors for different portlets in my `portal-ext.properties`.

These are the lines i added to the portal-ext.properties file:

```
editor.wysiwyg.default=tinymce
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.blogs.edit_entry.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.calendar.edit_configuration.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.enterprise_admin.view.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.invitation.edit_configuration.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.journal.edit_article_content.jsp=fckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.journal.edit_article_content_xsd_el.jsp=fckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.journal.edit_configuration.jsp=fckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.login.configuration.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.mail.edit.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.mail.edit_message.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.message_boards.edit_configuration.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.shopping.edit_configuration.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.wiki.edit.html.jsp=ckeditor
```

However, it seems that it is always the default editor that is taken and all other settings are ignored. Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

I also tried leaving out the default editor by using `editor.wysiwyg.default=` but then no editor appears when I want to add or edit an article.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

recently, I added these settings to portal-ext.properties of a liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4 install and the editors were changed accordingly. So, probably no bug at least here:

```
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.message_boards.configuration.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.message_boards.edit_message.bb_code.jsp=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.message_boards.edit_message.html.jsp=ckeditor
```

I did not add a `editor.wysiwyg.default=...` in the portal-ext.properties.